# Proper way to start activity in background

Tags: android, service

I need to do a logout after some time, so I'm opening the login window in my app using.

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Problem is that, if the user has my app in the background, my activity will pop up.

Is there a way to easily open an activity but keep my app in the background?

Comment: Activity is a foreground entity. It will be in the foreground only. You can't have it if your app is in the background. It's like being visible and invisible at the same time.

Comment: I don't think my problem here is clear. My app is indeed in the background, when I open a new activity: startActivity (because some process in the background), my app will popup to the foreground, but I don't want that. It's not true that you cannot have an activity when your app is in the background because that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement "local logout" after some time and when user returns to activity you can detect it. More: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with Android appliaction component **Service**.

you can read about it in official documentation by links below.

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service#java
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=en

Initialize your Service

```
public class MyBackgroundService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() { 

    //onCreate - Service created  
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //onDestroy - Service destroyed (Stopped)
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        //onStart - Service started
    }
}
```

Then call Service in your Main Activity

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyBackgroundService.class));
```

And don't forget about declare in Manifest.

```
<service android:enabled="true" 
android:name=".MyBackgroundService" />
```